# Normal Distribution, Probability of $P(X^2-4X<5)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Here is the question I am currently working on:

Suppose $X$ is normally distributed with mean, $\mu=2$ and standard deviation $\sigma=3$. Find $P(X^2-4X<5)$

I'm not sure what it wants me to do here or what to try, any help is appreciated.

Comment: For which $X$ does that inequality hold?  What is the probability that $X$ is in one of those regions?

Comment: @lulu Oh geez, yeah that should have been pretty obvious. For some reason I was trying think of a way to formulate a distribution for $X^2-4X$ which is clearly the wrong approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you are asked to calculate the probability of the set $\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid x^x-4x<5\}$. The "problem" is that the normal distribution function only "works" if you want to calculate the probability of sets like  $\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid a\leq x\leq b\}$. In those cases you simply plug in the values into the normal distribution function and get something like $P(a\leq X\leq b)=P(\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid a\leq x\leq b\})=\Phi(b)-\Phi(a)$.

Bearing this in mind, try to manipulate the set that is defined by $\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid x^x-4x<5\}$ in a way that it looks like the above described set. Then, plug in the bounds into the normal distribution function.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$X^2-4X<5 \iff(X+1)(X-5)<0\iff-1<X<5$$